# Numbering of a table with three equations while centering them with equal sign cause me a lot of trouble

Tags: tables, equations, numbering

I want to reproduce this image (Table in Latex.png).[image]

I am using Texmaker. Any help with that would be greatly appreciated. I need this because I am writing an article. I am an intermediate learner of LaTeX. If to simpliy you can put only one  number at the right, I would not mind. And of course, I need to b e able to reference it. I know it is a lot, but it will be a good lesson for all.

I thank you in advance for your trouble.

Mario

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX.SE. Pleae tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: what you try so far? Try to insert  each equation in the own minipage.

Comment: Don't you think numbering like that potentially confuses the reader? The (1) and (2) become a bit hidden compared to (3). I would use only one number.

Comment: After looking at my document, I realize that it is looking  odd. But nevertheless, the answers that I received are very instructive.

Answer (score 1):

By use of `cases` of `mathtools` package, inserted in the `minipage`s as I mentioned in comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{rcases}
         1   &   t>0 \\
        -1   &   t<0
        \end{rcases}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{rcases}
         1   &   t>0 \\
        -1   &   t<0
        \end{rcases}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{rcases}
         1   &   t>0 \\
        -1   &   t<0
        \end{rcases}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I should have specified that I use Texmaker in conjunction with MikTex. Your solution worked but MikTex had to install 8 packages. For me, I will have to learn how to manipulate that. But the result is there. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you explain what is the use of the % in your code please?

Comment: @M.Lemelin, `to see, what it due, test answer, where you remove it. `\noindent` remove indent of the first minipage. if after it is empty space, then minipage will move to right fortiny space. This is prevent by `%˛` immediately after `\noindent` command. In general, `%` comment code in line after it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use one of the main LaTeX document classes, i.e., `article`, `report`, or `book`, or a document class that's based on of these classes, the following example may be of interest to you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'aligned' env.
\usepackage{showframe}  % draw frame lines around text block

\begin{document}
\[
\left.
\begin{aligned}
  x &= r\cos\phi,\\
  y &= r\sin\phi,
\end{aligned}
\right\rbrace
\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)
\qquad
\left.
\begin{aligned}
  x &= r\cos\phi,\\
  y &= r\sin\phi,\\
  z &= z,
\end{aligned}
\right\rbrace
\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)
\qquad
\left.
\begin{aligned}
  x &= r\cos\theta,\\
  y &= r\sin\theta\cos\phi,\\
  z &= z\sin\theta\sin\phi.
\end{aligned}
\right\rbrace
\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution worked when we look at the equations. Unfortunately, even though I love the idea of a box around it, the code create three box??? See the image in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/df4lko00ynvrnj1/Three_box.png?dl=0).

Comment: I forgot to say that I thank you very much for your response. It fell reassuring to know that you can find help so fast here.

Comment: @M.Lemelin - The rectangular frame boxes are drawn because the `showframe` package is loaded in the code shown above. The upshot? Don't load the `showframe` package in you real document.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Right braces for emphasis are obtained with `right=\empheqbigrbrace` in `empheq` environment
2. Equations may get side-by-side numbering when using `minipage` environment. It is provided by LaTeX itself, but a better way to do it is with `adjustbox` environment

Code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={\dimexpr 0.333\linewidth - 1em \relax}, valign=m}
    
    \begin{empheq}[right=\empheqbigrbrace]{equation}
        \begin{alignedat}{2}
            x &= r \cos\phi,
            \\
            y &= r \sin\phi,
        \end{alignedat}
    \end{empheq}
    
\end{adjustbox}%
\hspace{\fill}%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={\dimexpr 0.333\linewidth - 1em \relax}, valign=m}
    
    \begin{empheq}[right=\empheqbigrbrace]{equation}
        \begin{alignedat}{2}
            x &= r \cos\phi,
            \\
            y &= r \sin\phi,
            \\
            z &= z,
        \end{alignedat}
    \end{empheq}
    
\end{adjustbox}%
\hspace{\fill}%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={\dimexpr 0.333\linewidth - 1em \relax}, valign=m}
    
    \begin{empheq}[right=\empheqbigrbrace]{equation}
        \begin{alignedat}{2}
            x &= r \cos\theta,
            \\
            y &= r \sin\theta \cos\phi,
            \\
            z &= r \sin\theta \sin\phi.
        \end{alignedat}
    \end{empheq}
    
\end{adjustbox}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of using `alignedat{2}` environments when there's a single alignment point per row? Should it maybe be `alignedat{1}` (or `aligned`)?

Comment: `alginedat` allows for better control of spacing

Comment: What spacing are you controlling? Please elaborate.

Comment: `alginedat` does not insert spaces between columns, meaning I get to set spaces to my exact desires. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672096/how-can-i-align-without-spaces

Comment: I stll don't understand: Since there's just one alignment point per row, what do you mean by "I get to set spaces to my exact desires"?